# How to add key to an existing array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array (as seen below)...

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "orderid:100000154"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "shipping_method:channelunitycustomrate_channelunitycustomrate"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "qty_ordered:1.0000"
  [3]=>
  string(26) "shipping_firstname:John"
  [4]=>
  string(24) "shipping_lastname:Doe"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "shipping_company:"
  [6]=>
  string(36) "shipping_street1:123 Fake Street"
  [7]=>
  string(17) "shipping_street2:"
  [8]=>
  string(20) "shipping_city:LAUREL"
  [9]=>
  string(28) "shipping_postcode:20723-1042"
  [10]=>
  string(24) "shipping_region:Maryland"
  [11]=>
  string(19) "shipping_country:US"
  [12]=>
  string(21) "vendor_sku:3397001814"
  [13]=>
  string(16) "vendor_linecode:"
  [14]=>
  string(1) "
"
}
```

I have a desired key setup in this array -- the key for the first value would be orderid, so I'd like orderid => 1000000154

How would I go about this? I believe I have to explode the array again, but I'm not sure about the way to write it and none of my attempts have gotten me any closer.

Thanks!

Comment: loop over the array, explode on `:` and assign key/value to a new array.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through and set the keys and values using `explode()`. Use the first item in the exploded array as the key and the second as the value, then unset the existing item (the numeric-indexed array element) to clean up.

```
$input = array(
    "orderid:100000154",
    "shipping_method:channelunitycustomrate_channelunitycustomrate",
    "qty_ordered:1.0000",
    "shipping_firstname:John",
    "shipping_lastname:Doe",
    "shipping_company:",
    "shipping_street1:123 Fake Street",
    "shipping_street2:",
    "shipping_city:LAUREL",
    "shipping_postcode:20723-1042",
    "shipping_region:Maryland",
    "shipping_country:US",
    "vendor_sku:3397001814",
    "vendor_linecode:",
    "
    "
);

foreach($input as $key => $val) {
    if(strstr($val, ":")) {
        $exploded = explode(":", $val);
        $input[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
    }
    unset($input[$key]);
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($input);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs:

```
array(14) {
    ["orderid"]=>
      string(9) "100000154"
    ["shipping_method"]=>
      string(45) "channelunitycustomrate_channelunitycustomrate"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>
      string(6) "1.0000"
    ["shipping_firstname"]=>
      string(4) "John"
    ["shipping_lastname"]=>
      string(3) "Doe"
    ["shipping_company"]=>
      string(0) ""
    ["shipping_street1"]=>
      string(15) "123 Fake Street"
    ["shipping_street2"]=>
      string(0) ""
    ["shipping_city"]=>
      string(6) "LAUREL"
    ["shipping_postcode"]=>
      string(10) "20723-1042"
    ["shipping_region"]=>
      string(8) "Maryland"
    ["shipping_country"]=>
      string(2) "US"
    ["vendor_sku"]=>
      string(10) "3397001814"
    ["vendor_linecode"]=>
      string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach($yourArray as $row) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(":", $row);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```